# Keep records in master Set with no Ids

Tags: apex, batch, set

I'm using a master `Set` to keep all created records and to remove duplicates before insertion. The problem is that once the record gets inserted, it gets Id assigned to it and records in master `Set` get updated with it (I know those are just references). I've tried to clone the set (see the code) before inserting the records but it didn't help.

```
    if ( contentDocumentLinks.size() > 0 ){
    // adding to masterContentDocumentLinks
    this.masterContentDocumentLinks.addAll(contentDocumentLinks.clone());
    insert new List<ContentDocumentLink>(contentDocumentLinks);
    contentDocumentLinks.clear();
}

for ( Attachment attachment : duplicateAttachments ){

    contentDocumentLinks.add( new ContentDocumentLink(
        linkedEntityId = attachment.parentId,
        // this actually returns contentDocumentId put into description field in prev step
        contentDocumentId = this.attachmentMap.get( attachment.name ),
        shareType = 'I'
    ));
}
// trying to remove any records existing in masterContentDocumentLinks
ContentDocumentLinks.removeAll(this.masterContentDocumentLinks);
// second iteration to insert contentDocumentLinks - same as above
```

**My question is how could I keep contentDocumentLinks without their Ids?** I could only think of having master `Set` as a `String` `(linkedEntityId + contentDocumentId)`, but would prefer to have an actual contentDocumentLinks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to deepClone instead, so something like this:

```
masterContentDocumentLinks.addAll(
    new List<ContentDocumentLink>(contentDocumentLinks).deepClone(false, false, false)
);
```

Unlike clone(), which just copies the top-level object (the Set, for example), deepClone copies the individual elements contained in a list or map, so that they become truly independent values.

Comment: Is deepClone available on Set?

Comment: @Oleksiy no, that's why I made the list first, then cloned, then added.

Comment: great. Not sure how costly List -> Set transformation is, but it worked! Thank you.